# How to make page contents dependent on the selected row value

Tags: php

so i'm making some sort of contact/quote management webpage for the company I'm working for. Can someone please help clarify what's going wrong here? When the user clicks on a specific row, i want them to be redirected to a page that will have text displaying the database values related to the row selected. I'm attempting to do it by session but it isn't working. Please help
Here is my code...

quotemanager.php

```
     <?php
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {

  echo '
  <tr id ="table">
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="quote_id">'.$row["quote_id"].'</td>
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="first_name">'.$row["first_name"].'</td>
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="last_name">'.$row["last_name"].'</td>
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="home_phone">'.$row["home_phone"].'</td>
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="cell_phone">'.$row["cell_phone"].'</td>
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="work_phone">'.$row["work_phone"].'</td>
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="email">'.$row["email"].'</td>
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="company_name">'.$row["company_name"].'</td>
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="property_address">'.$row["property_address"].'</td>
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="prefered_method">'.$row["prefer_method"].'</td>      
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="prefered_date">'.$row["prefered_date"].'</td>
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="prefered_time">'.$row["prefered_time"].'</td>
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="project_detail">'.$row["project_detail"].'</td>
   <td data-url="quoteupdate.php?$id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" 
name="project_type">'.$row["project_type"].'</td>
</tr>
';
}
$_SESSION['quote_id'] = $row;    
?>
```

quoteupdate.php

```
<?php
session_start();

?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Managing Quote # <?php echo print_r ($_SESSION['quote_id']) ?> </h1>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass as `GET` variable, not Session:

In quotemanager.php, fix the url, replacing `$id` with `quote_id`

```
<td data-url="quoteupdate.php?quote_id=' . $row['quote_id'] . '" type="text" name="quote_id">'.$row["quote_id"].'</td>
```

In quoteupdate.php

```
<h1>Managing Quote # <?php echo print_r ($_GET['quote_id']) ?> </h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, It doesnt seem to be working still though. Is there anything else I need to do on quotemanager.php?

Comment: What's not working? Does it redirects to quoteupdate?

Comment: Yes it does, the error thats coming up is "Notice: Undefined index: quote_id in" ...

Comment: My bad. You need to use `quote_id` in the link insted. Updated.

Comment: Thanks alot, that appears to be working. Could I ask you if you know why its showing a 1 at the end of the print_r? so for example if the id is 3, itll show 31. thanks alot for your help

Comment: You should use `echo` or `print_r`, but not `echo print_r`